# error while deleting row in gridview via 3 tier

Tags: c#, .net, 3-tier

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This is the error which i m getting while i trying to delete .. row from my grid  view

this is in .. page_ load

```
gvDetails.DataSource =myBl.DeleteAllCountry(int.Parse(gvDetails.SelectedRow.ToString()));
```

on data access layer

```
   public DataTable DeleteCountry(int country_id)
    {
        DataTable dltcontry = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=a8-pc\sqlexpress;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.connection= con;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "sp_DeleteCountry";
            con.Open();
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("country_id", @country_id);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            da.Fill(dltcontry);
            con.Close();
        }
```

and in business layer the code is like

```
  public DataTable DeleteAllCountry(int country_id)
  {
     return mydtLayer.DeleteCountry(country_id);
  }
```

Comment: Please format your question properly and use proper english..this is not SMS..

Comment: You have stored procedure for delete and you can delete by calling `ExecuteNonQuery` but why you again use same for get data?

Comment: Please state your question more clearly. This exception looks like a NullPointer-Exception. Usually the debug-output provides a line-number where the exception occurred, including a stack-trace. Use that line-number to investigate the error further.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to correct, you need to set connection to your command

```
cmd.Connection =con;
```

or in the constructor as below

```
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
            queryString, connection);
```

Another problem is you try to convert selected `gvDetails.SelectedRow` to int value

check `gvDetails.selectedRows.Count` before you get value of selected row

if you have selection you can then get cell valu of your country_id column as below

```
 gvDetails.SelectedRow.cells("country_id").Text
```

now you can convert this to a int value by using `int.TryParse` and if it is success send to your BL function to delete the record

Comment: done that ...  but how to solve next still getting that error

Comment: which line? debug and check which line and which object is null

Comment: gvDetails.DataSource =myBl.DeleteAllCountry(int.Parse(gvDetails.SelectedRow.ToString()));

Comment: Are you stepping through your code to check which variable it is has a null value?  It's hard to tell from this if SelectedRow has a value, or if its being thrown within that method.